# Manga where the main character loses his arm in a fight with a demon god and get reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I'm looking for a reincarnation manga where the main character fights and loses to a demon god, taking his arm, and gets reincarnated with God given abilities, and raids a dungeon to gain a dragon heart and proceeds to go after more dragons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character or place names?  Any notable details of the art or portrayal of the characters?

Answer (score 1):

[*Doom Breaker*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147172/Doom_Breaker?q=doom%20&cat=manga) is what you are probably what you are looking for

> Zephyr is the last human fighting evil in a world abandoned by the gods. When he is killed in battle by Tartarus, the god of destruction, all hope for humanity seems lost. But Zephyr’s fate is not sealed -- the gods who find his battles entertaining have gifted him a second chance at life, as he is sent ten years into the past, back to when he was a slave instead of the most powerful human alive. Can Zephyr get his revenge against Tartarus and save the woman he loves, or is he doomed to repeat the past?

[image: Cover page for Manhwa]

Doom breaker or Suicide battle God is a pretty popular Manhwa. Zephyr goes back in time to correct back his mistakes he made during is first timeline and save as many people as he can.

[image: Here is the Dragon transformation]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).